# Can we make use of some volatile liquid and atmospheric heat to generate electricity?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

Is it possible to use some volatile liquid with a **low melting point** (like ammonia) *and* **atmospheric heat** to make energy? Can we make a volatile liquid like ammonia to evaporate due to atmospheric heat and make it rotate **turbines to make electrical energy**? Is this possible?

**PS**: I'm new to such the topic of energy making and hope there aren't any errors.

Its very much like a thermal power-plant except that in place of coal we use atmospheric heat and in place of water we use a liquid with a low melting point- seems crazy, but I'm curious if this is scientifically and economically feasible.
Thank you!

Comment: A heat engine needs a temperature *difference*. So yes you can use atmospheric heat, but you also need something colder than the atmosphere to send the heat to.

Comment: What would your system do when all the ammonia has evaporated?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use such a system to *make* energy.  That would violate the conservation of energy.

You *can* use it to convert energy from thermal energy to mechanical energy though.   I believe this is what you really intended.

An engine that converts heat to mechanical work is a [Heat engine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine).  You can see there are many types of heat engines.  They run off different cycles and have various applications.  One with ammonia like you describe would be a form of [phase change heat engine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine#Phase-change_cycles).

The specific application you're looking for may not be possible though; because you suggest running an engine off atmospheric heat.  The thing is, for a heat engine, you need a hot and cold resovior.  The heat transfer to run the engine requires a temperature *difference*.  If all your surroundings are the same temperature, you cannot extract the heat as work.  If one end were a little warmer, it would be possible to use ammonia as a phase change substance in the thermodynamic cycle.

Another potential topic of interest might be [exergy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exergy) which is the available energy.  Air at the same temperature has no exergy.  when there's a temperature difference, the act of the systems trying to reach equilibrium can do work, which is what we utilize in thermodynamics.

Comment: Thank you sir! but can we use thet mechanical energy to create electrical energy?

Comment: Can we use atmospheric heat on one side and cold ocean water on the other side to create a temperature difference?

Comment: @Mayur Sure, but you won't get a lot of  power that way, since the temperature difference is usually quite small, and the ocean isn't always colder than the air.

Comment: @PM2Ring Is there some way to make this system more efficient?

Comment: @Mayur I'm afraid not. For example, let's say the air is at 300 kelvin, around 27 Celsius, and the water is 5 degrees colder. The energy difference for air between those temperatures is around 6 joules per litre. But according to Carnot's theorem only 5/300 of that energy can be converted to work under perfect ideal conditions. In a real heat engine, the efficiency will be significantly lower, since there are no perfect heat conductors or insulators, and there are losses due to friction, etc.

Comment: @Mayur OTOH, rather than just using ambient air, you could use solar heating to provide the heat in your hot reservoir. But even then the system needs to be quite large to offset the losses mentioned in my previous comment.